# Dr. Java turtle project -- I can't seem to debug my errors

Tags: java, turtle-graphics

I am trying to complete a Turtle Project in Dr. Java that has multiple rooms with questions to advance and I can't seem to find and fix the errors that I am getting.

Here is my code:

```
0
import java.awt.*;
public class TurtleDrawing
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
boolean one = roomOne();
}
public static boolean roomOne();
{
World wor = new World(500,500);
Turtle turOne = new Turtle(0,0, wor);
Picture picOne = new Picture("grocery.jpg");
Picture pitTwo = new Picture("anteater.webp");
turOne.penUp();
turone.moveTo(200,200);
turOne.drop(picOne);
turOne.moveTo(300,100);
turOne.drop(picTwo);
turOne.hide();
turOne.forward(1);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Dequavis the anteater is shopping for 
bananas at his local grocery store");                 
String str = JOptionPane.showImputDialog(null, "If each bundle costs 3 
dollars and he buys 2 bundles how much will he pay?");
if (str.equals("6"))
  return true;
else return false;
}
World wor = new World(1100,800);
Turtle turOne = new Turtle(wor);
turOne.penUp();
Picture picOne = new Picture ("space.jpg");
turOne.moveTo(0,0);
turOne.drop (picOne);

Turtle turTwo = new Turtle(wor);
turTwo.penUp();
Picture picTwo = new Picture ("rocket.png");
turTwo.moveTo(200,500);
turTwo.drop (picTwo);
turTwo.forward(1);

Turtle turThree = new Turtle(wor);
turThree.penUp();
Picture picThree = new Picture ("unircorn.png");
turTwo.moveTo(700,600);
turThree.drop (picThree);
turThree.forward(1);

Turtle turFour = new Turtle(wor);
turFour.penUp();
Picture picFour = new Picture ("spongebob.png");
turTwo.moveTo(400,600);
turFour.drop (picFour);
turFour.forward(1);
turOne.penUp();
double x = 0 ;
double y = 0;
int t = 0;
turOne.setColor(Color.BLUE);
while (t < 200)
{
  if(t > 0)
    turOne.penDown();
x = (16 * Math.sin(t)* Math.sin(t) * Math.sin(t))* -1 + 500 ;
y = (13 * Math.cos(t) - 5 * Math.cos (2 * t) - 2 * Math.cos(3 * t))- 
Math.cos(4 * t) * -10 + 400;
t = t + 1;
turOne.moveTo((int)x, (int)y);
}
}
public static void heart( Turtle turOne , int startX, int startY)
{
double x = 0; 

  double y = 0;
  int t = 0;
  turOne.penUp();
if( t % 3 == 1)
  turOne.setColor(Color.PINK);
if( t % 3 == 2)
}
}
```

I have tried getting help from multiple people and I can't seem to fix it.

Comment: What sort of errors? Compile errors? Run time errors? What errors do you get? Or does something just go wrong?

Comment: Please add in your stacktrace. Also, on a brief glance, one of the errors is probably `turone.moveTo(200,200);` which should be `turOne.moveTo(200,200);`

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Your errors seem to consist of typos:

```
showImputDialog -> showInputDialog
pitTwo -> picTwo
turone -> turOne
unircorn -> unicorn
```

Copy and paste errors:

```
Turtle turFour = new Turtle(wor);
turFour.penUp();
Picture picFour = new Picture ("spongebob.png");
turTwo.moveTo(400,600);  // probably should be turFour
turFour.drop (picFour);
turFour.forward(1);
```

And incomplete code fragments:

```
if( t % 3 == 1)
  turOne.setColor(Color.PINK);
if( t % 3 == 2)
```

The worst of which is about 30 lines of code that belong to a method that never got declared!

I don't have Dr. Java turtle to compare against but below is my rework of your code fixing as many problems as I could detect:

```
import java.awt.*;

public class TurtleDrawing
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        boolean one = roomOne();
    }

    public static boolean roomOne()
    {
        World wor = new World(500, 500);

        Picture picOne = new Picture("grocery.jpg");
        Picture picTwo = new Picture("anteater.webp");

        Turtle turOne = new Turtle(0, 0, wor);
        turOne.penUp();
        turOne.moveTo(200, 200);
        turOne.drop(picOne);
        turOne.moveTo(300, 100);
        turOne.drop(picTwo);
        turOne.hide();
        turOne.forward(1);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Dequavis the anteater is shopping for bananas at his local grocery store");
        String str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "If each bundle costs 3 dollars and he buys 2 bundles how much will he pay?");

        return str.equals("6");
    }

    public static void unamed_function()
    {

        World wor = new World(1100, 800);

        Picture picOne = new Picture("space.jpg");
        Picture picTwo = new Picture("rocket.png");
        Picture picThree = new Picture("unicorn.png");
        Picture picFour = new Picture ("spongebob.png");

        Turtle turOne = new Turtle(wor);
        turOne.penUp();
        turOne.moveTo(0, 0);
        turOne.drop(picOne);

        Turtle turTwo = new Turtle(wor);
        turTwo.penUp();
        turTwo.moveTo(200, 500);
        turTwo.drop(picTwo);
        turTwo.forward(1);

        Turtle turThree = new Turtle(wor);
        turThree.penUp();
        turThree.moveTo(700, 600);
        turThree.drop(picThree);
        turThree.forward(1);

        Turtle turFour = new Turtle(wor);
        turFour.penUp();
        turFour.moveTo(400, 600);
        turFour.drop(picFour);
        turFour.forward(1);

        turOne.setColor(Color.BLUE);

        int t = 0;

        while (t < 200)
        {
            double x = (16 * Math.sin(t) * Math.sin(t) * Math.sin(t)) * -1 + 500;
            double y = (13 * Math.cos(t) - 5 * Math.cos(2 * t) - 2 * Math.cos(3 * t)) - Math.cos(4 * t) * -10 + 400;

            turOne.moveTo((int)x, (int)y);

            t = t + 1;
            turOne.penDown();
        }
    }

    public static void heart(Turtle turOne, int startX, int startY)
    {
        double x = 0; 
        double y = 0;
        int t = 0;

        turOne.penUp();

        if (t % 3 == 1)
        {
            turOne.setColor(Color.PINK);
        }
        else if (t % 3 == 2)
        {
            turOne.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
    }
}
```